# ReactJS: update record of an object of an array within an array

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactJS, I was doing a practice example where I have to update a product and it’s quantity. The final output is required in the following form:

```
productData = [
    name: '',
    code: '',
    Quantity:  [specificationName: "", quantity: ""]
]
```

I have added functionality for adding record in productData. But I am facing problem in updating Quantity array. Instead of updating data, a new record is added in Quantity array. I am not using index because I have read that it’s not a good approach when our data is non-static.

Below is my code:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
   let productData = {};
   let specificationQuantity = [];

   const productForm = new FormData(event.target);

   for (var [key, value] of productForm.entries()) {
            
     if (key !== "name" && key !== "code" ){
              
       let updateQuantity = {
           specificationName: key,
           quantity: value
       }

       specificationQuantity.push(updateQuantity)
     }
            
    productData = {
      name: colorForm.get('name'),
      code: colorForm.get('code'),
      Quantity: specificationQuantity
    }
  }
  this.state.productData.push(productData)
}
```

Let's say, I have the following 2 record after addition

```
  {
    code: "#0000C3",
    name: "Blue",
    Quantity: Array(2)
       0: {name: "", quantity: ""}     // this record is automatically created idk why
       1: {name: "v1", quantity: "1"}
  }
  {
    code: "#00001E",
    name: "Black",
    Quantity: Array(2)
       0: {name: "", quantity: ""}  
       1: {name: "v2", quantity: "2"}
  }
```

and when I try to update the quantity of “v1” to 3 then only that quantity which is in **Blue** should be updated like {name: ‘v1’, quantity: ‘3’}
but I am getting the following result

```
{
    code: "#0000C3",
    name: "Blue",
    Quantity: Array(3)
       0: {name: "", quantity: ""}     // this record is automatically created idk why
       1: {name: "v1", quantity: "1"}
       2: {name: "v1", quantity: "3"}
  }
  {
    code: "#00001E",
    name: "Black",
    Quantity: Array(3)
       0: {name: "", quantity: ""}  
       1: {name: "v2", quantity: "2"}
       2: {name: "v1", quantity: "3"}
  }
```

Comment: @Tushar is right. Use just `this.setState({})` for modification of state values

Comment: @OnerT. I have tried it but it still adds a new record on update

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line

```
this.state.productData.push(productData)
```

You are actually mutating the state directly which is why you are facing unexpected behaviour.

Please have a look at this:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: I have changed it to this.setState({productData: productData}) but it's still adds a new row on updation

Comment: Can you create a pen and share the link so that we could have a better look at what's going on?